# Query and decode json form mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have this JSON encoded code in my mysql database:

```
{"Suggestion":{"Title":"Casinos","Text":"maybe it will be good if its there casinos "},"ID":6,"VoteNo":[],"Status":"Voting","Player":{"SteamID":"STEAM_0:1:36988062","Name":"Pepi"},"Approved":{"Name":"Nido Johnson","Is":true,"SteamID":"STEAM_0:0:47457253"},"VoteYes":{"1":"STEAM_0:0:56939043","2":"STEAM_0:0:55948188","3":"STEAM_0:1:25856984","4":"STEAM_0:1:40894071"}}
```

And i want to query and decode it to echo it at my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use a php "json_decode()" function to decode a json encoded data.
Basically json_decode() function converts JSON data to a PHP array.

**Syntax: json_decode( data, dataTypeBoolean, depth, options )**

**data** : -  The json data that you want to decode in PHP.

**dataTypeBoolean(Optional)** :-  boolean that makes the function return a PHP Associative Array if set to "true", or return a PHP stdClass object if you omit this parameter or set it to "false". Both data types can be accessed like an array and use array based PHP loops for parsing.

**depth** :- Optional recursion limit. Use an integer as the value for this parameter.

**options** :- Optional JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING parameter.

***Now Comes to your Code***

```
    $json_string = '{"Suggestion":{"Title":"Casinos","Text":"maybe it will be good if its there casinos "},"ID":6,"VoteNo":[],"Status":"Voting","Player":{"SteamID":"STEAM_0:1:36988062","Name":"Pepi"},"Approved":{"Name":"Nido Johnson","Is":true,"SteamID":"STEAM_0:0:47457253"},"VoteYes":{"1":"STEAM_0:0:56939043","2":"STEAM_0:0:55948188","3":"STEAM_0:1:25856984","4":"STEAM_0:1:40894071"}}';
```

**Assign a valid json data to a variable $json_string within single quot's ('') as
   json string already have double quots.**

```
// here i am decoding a json string by using a php 'json_decode' function, as mentioned above & passing a true parameter to get a PHP associative array otherwise it will bydefault return a PHP std class objecy array.

    / just can check here your encoded array data.
// echo '<pre>';
// print_r($json_decoded_data);

// loop to extract data from an array
foreach ($json_decoded_data as $key => $value) {
    echo "$key <br/>";
    foreach($value as $k=>$data)
    {
        echo "$k | $data <br/>";
    }

}
```